# PHP: Find words with in a vocabulary and add a link to it

Tags: php, hyperlink, replace, words

I have a list of words that I would like to find in a text. I want to replace these words with a link to a page corresponding to it. This would be used for authors, some vocabulary words or references.

Any idea how to implement this? are there any open source packages that do this?

Thank you.

Comment: would you like to replace every occurrence of the word/s with link and is their any specific pattern followed in the links.

Answer (score 0):

Have I understood your idea?

```
<?php

str_replace('Romeo and Juliet', '<a href="http://shakespeare.mit.edu/romeo_juliet/">Romeo and Juliet</a>');

?>
```

Comment: Yes and no. I have a list of words that need to be matched to different texts, this list of words may grow or shrink. But I don't want to add a line with a str_replace for every word in my list. The final result would be to replace Romeo and Juliet with a link similar to the one you have provided.

Comment: you should not add it for every line, please be more specific as I can't really understand what concretely do you need

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question and explanation. this is what I'm trying to do. $content = preg_replace(array($pattern1,$pattern2, $pattern3), '', $content);
But I'm wondering if there are any php packages that actually match custom vocabularies to content. there are sites where you see multiple words highlighted (for example computer) and when you roll over computer services pop's up. They are not entering this manually but replacing behind the scenes some words and based on that they add a custom link or JS

Comment: that's not a problem, just explain better and we will help you